# Undefined index error - why does this still work with error suppression?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an error "Notice: Undefined index: srSend" in the code below. I have two questions:

i) Why does this code work if I error-suppress? Does it matter that the undefined index is an error? ii) How could I correct this error, regardless?

```
<?php

//db connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}


if($_POST['srSend'] && $_POST['srEmail']) {
    //check if email already taken
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT user_pin FROM users WHERE user_email = ?")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", strtolower($_POST['srEmail']));
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($user_pin);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: Do not suppress errors.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, not everything is black and white, error suppression is recommended for a production environment.

Comment: Use the isset function: if (isset($_POST['srSend']) && $_POST['srSend'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code still works when you suppress errors because it's a "Notice". There are different levels of errors in PHP and you can configure PHP to only show certain types of errors. Here's a complete list of Error constants : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/errorfunc.constants.php Notice errors are disabled by default in PHP because your code will still work fine, but it's always good to fix them.

This notice happens because the indexes you are trying to access do not exist. You can use isset() to check if they do exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress this error you should check to see if the variable is set. In fact its a best practice because if the variable is "false" or 0 then it could lead to unintended behaviour

```
if(isset($_POST['srSend']) && isset($_POST['srEmail'])) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is notice

```
 Notice: Undefined index: srSend"
```

when the php code initially runs `$_POST['srSend']` will not be set so you will receive this notice. you should check with  `isset()` or `empty()` in if condition like  `if(isset($_POST['srSend']))`

Answer (score 0):

> i) The error works because it is valid to query on a blank user_email field which is what is happening when the index is undefined.
>
> ii) You can correct the error by either checking for the existence of $_POST['srEmail'] with isset or empty and providing a default if it's not available.

**For Example**

```
// set email to blank if one not provided in the POST 
$email = isset($_POST["srEmail"])?isset($_POST["srEmail"]:"");
```

> iii) You should be able answer WHY you receive any of the notices because they can be indications of errors in your code. Even if the source of the notice is known and not detrimental to your application you should address the notices when they appear so you can continue to develop with error reporting turned on without it disrupting your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Run-time notices occurs because the script found something that might be an error, but could also happen when running a script normally. The `@` operator temporarily sets the error reporting level to 0 for that line. If that line triggers an error, the error handler will still be called, but it will be called with an error level of 0.

Notice errors matters like any other critical errors. Errors slow down your app and you really should design you application not to throw errors, even a small one. Many other languages will completely die in situations where PHP happily continues script execution.

You need to check if the variable is set before moving further:

```
if(isset($_POST['srSend']) && isset($_POST['srEmail'])) {
```